# HP UX max stack size limit

Tags: unix, stack, size

What is the max stack size limit of 32 bit process in HP-UX B.11.31 or what is the max stack size that can be alloacted to a 32 bit process in HP -UX

Comment: Check : `ulimit -a` (OR) `ulimit -a | grep 'stack'`

Answer (score 0):

MAX STACK SIZE LIMIT

Default
      32 bit: 0x800000 (8MB)

```
  64 bit: 0x10000000 (256MB)

Allowed values
  32 bit minimum: 0x40000

  32 bit maximum: 0x17F00000

  64 bit minimum: 0x40000

  64 bit maximum: 0x80000000
```